# C++ - extract numbers from a string

Tags: c++, string

Let's say we have a C style string in C++ in the format `[4 letters] [number] [number] ...`. For example, the string may look like:

```
   abcd 1234    -6242          1212
```

It should be noted that the string is expected to have too much whitespace (as seen above).

How would I extract these three numbers and store them in an array?

Comment: I think you would have to rely on using the spaces as delimiters

Comment: @user2064000 in response to the 'objections' raised in the comments at my answer, I'd suggest you to look at the right side of this screen and follow some of the "Related" links...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A job for stringstreams, see it live: **http://ideone.com/e8GjMg**

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss(" abcd 1234    -6242          1212");

    std::string s;
    int a, b, c;

    iss >> s >> a >> b >> c;

    std::cout << s << " " << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
abcd 1234 -6242 1212
```

Comment: @phresnel Well, you know... I'm not new around here. Some people learn either way. I can guarantee you that (a) eager learners ***will*** get the important directions from this answer (b) people that don't, won't "get it" from an _educational_ answer either. In short, Stackoverflow isn't for text-book tutoring. It's about volunteering answers to unstuck other programmers/share experience. _Feel free to ignore both the question and the answer if it's not your cup of tea._ Thank you

Comment: @not-sehe: Point taken, I was hoping that you may add at least some explanations, but your last comment isn't wrong. (sidenote: I removed my comments)